# Ionic-Native issue in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

I have added a Cordova file transfer plugin from Ionic native and imported transfer from ionic native to my application page
I am not getting any syntax error as well as command prompt errors
But when I run my application using Ionic serve it is showing me 
**{*Cannot find module "ionic-native"*}**
Can anyone please help me on this

Comment: cordova plugins dont run in `ionic serve`. you have to use device or emulator

Answer (score 0):

Did u check it properly, weather u have installed ionic-native ? 
Plus which version of ionic are you using, in ionic 3 (launched recently) they removed ionic-native and kept it seperately in @ionic-native. And u'll have to indivisually install every plugin u r using. 
http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-native-3-x/

Comment: I have used ionic native only I imported @ionic-native/transfer

Comment: @VenkateshNaidu just do this.,it will be fine..,npm install @ionic-native/core --save

Comment: @VenkateshNaidu in your question u mentioned that the error u r getting is this  - " it is showing me {Cannot find module "ionic-native"} " . That means that you are still using ionic-native package, which doesn't exist anymore, check where are you using it and remove it.